# How to initialize a Part from a String (the file name)?

Tags: jsf, file-upload, initialization, jsf-2.2

How do I get my file (javax.servlet.http.Part) from my JSF form? All what I have saved in the database is the file name.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. This restriction is already in HTML side. You can't preset the value of an `<input type="file">` field. That would be a major security hole as that would allow web pages to unaskingly upload completely arbitrary files from the client to the server.

You would as enduser not be happy when you visited a website which has something like this:

```
<form name="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="display:none">
    <input type="file" value="c:/path/to/passwords.txt" />
</form>
<script>document.upload.submit();</script>
```

That's why it's already in plain HTML not possible. JSF as being a HTML code generator can't do much against that.

Your best bet is a signed(!) Applet which uses Swing `JFileChooser` which you in turn embed in your web page. The `JFileChooser` allows initializing a default `File`. That would be more applicable if it concerns an Intranet page which should interact with a network disk file system.